# Contenteditable set carret on a child node

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having some difficulties while trying to set the carret after an `<i>` tag inside a `contenteditable`.

Here is what I have :

```
<p contenteditable="true"><i>H</i><i>e</i><i>l</i><i>l</i><i>o</i></p>
```

How do I put the carret after the .. let's say 3rd `<i>` tag here?

I already tried this solution :

```
var el = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
var range = document.createRange();
var sel = window.getSelection();
range.setStart(el.childNodes[0], 3);
range.collapse(true);
sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(range);
el.focus();
```

But I don't know how to make it work with the position of the `<i>` tags instead of the chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var el = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
var range = document.createRange();
var sel = window.getSelection();
range.setStart(el.childNodes[3], 0);
range.collapse(true);
sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(range);
el.focus();
```

```html
<p contenteditable="true"><i>H</i><i>e</i><i>l</i><i>l</i><i>o</i></p>
```

In `p` 5 child nodes are there, if you want to set caret at child node use `range.setStart(el.childNodes[3], 0);`

Comment: Thanks, pretty simple really ! I didn't understand the two parameters from the setStart function.